# Вывод чисел по порядку из базы данных MySQL

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Доброго времени суток!
Вопрос следующий:
Как должен выглядеть запрос в базу данных, чтоб мне вывело числа по порядку с 1 до 11 и при этом числа 10 и 11 будут стоять в конце, а не в начале. То есть должно учитывать не только первое число, но и последующие.

Comment: SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY field;

Comment: при условии, что field integer/long и т.п. :) если varchar, то не получится

Comment: > Вывод, из базы данных mysql, чисел по порядку

= Вывод чисел по порядку из базы данных mysql

Comment: @thunder, это ж почему не получится? Всё очень даже хорошо получается:

    SELECT * FROM `my_table` ORDER BY CAST(`type` AS UNSIGNED);

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Для сортировки результатов запроса предназначена конструкция `ORDER BY`. Пусть числа по которым нужно отсортировать находятся в поле `field` таблицы `my_table`. В этом случае можно воспользоваться запросом вида

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY field;
```

Если столбец `field`, строковый, например `VARCHAR` значения в нем потребуется привести к числовому типу

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY CAST(field AS UNSIGNED);
```